# Java proxyservlet post data to another server

Tags: java, proxy, http-post

I Need to create a java proxyservlet that sends all incoming data (XML) to another Server.
But how do i post my incoming data to the remote Server?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String server = "http://server.tld";
    String subURI = request.getRequestURI().split("/ProxyServlet")[1];
    System.out.println("ProxyServlet: " + server + subURI);
    URL remoteServer = new URL(server + subURI);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) remoteServer.openConnection();

    //somehow apply request to remoteServer and receive response        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i could solve it, with the help of [this article](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/IO_How_to/Byte_Array/Convert_InputStream_to_Byte_array.htm):

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String server = "http://server.tld";
    String subURI = request.getRequestURI().split("/ProxyServlet")[1];      
    System.out.println("ProxyServlet: " + server + subURI);     
    URL remoteServerURL = new URL(server+subURI);
    HttpURLConnection remoteServer = (HttpURLConnection) remoteServerURL.openConnection();
    remoteServer.setRequestMethod("POST");
    remoteServer.setDoOutput(true);
    remoteServer.getOutputStream().write(readBytes(request.getInputStream()));
    response.getOutputStream().write(readBytes(remoteServer.getInputStream()));
}

 /**
   * Read and return the entire contents of the supplied {@link InputStream stream}. This method always closes the stream when
   * finished reading.
   * 
   * @param stream the stream to the contents; may be null
   * @return the contents, or an empty byte array if the supplied reader is null
   * @throws IOException if there is an error reading the content
   */
  private byte[] readBytes( InputStream stream ) throws IOException {
      if (stream == null) return new byte[] {};
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      boolean error = false;
      try {
          int numRead = 0;
          while ((numRead = stream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
              output.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          error = true; // this error should be thrown, even if there is an error closing stream
          throw e;
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          error = true; // this error should be thrown, even if there is an error closing stream
          throw e;
      } finally {
          try {
              stream.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              if (!error) throw e;
          }
      }
      output.flush();
      return output.toByteArray();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as using CloseableHttpClient for newer as Java7 or using HttpClient for too old Java version?

Then read your OutPutStream into Byte Array and write to InputStream of CloseableHttpClient?